# Possible to copy property information in Device Manager?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, device-manager

In Windows 7 "Device Manager", is it possible to copy a device's property details (other than manually transcribing)?

If not, where are these properties and values stored? Perhaps I can go straight to the source (like the registry) and copy them from there.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can get the info you want via the MS System Information tool (msinfo32).

run `msinfo32.exe`. You can navigate to the device in question in the pane on the left, and copy its details with `Edit -> Select All` followed by `Edit -> Copy`, or you can use `File -> Export` to dump the devices' info to a text file. The export option is scoped\affected by the node selected on the left. If you export while the "System Summary" node is selected, you will get the details of all the devices, resources, and software components, or if you select "Components" you can export the information about all devices by themselves.

Heres an example of an export when I have `Components\Input\Keyboard` selected:

```
System Name: TiltedWindmill
[Keyboard]

Item    Value   
Description USB Input Device    
Name    Enhanced (101- or 102-key)  
Layout  00000409    
PNP Device ID   USB\VID_03F0&PID_0324\6&3B073303&0&6    
Number of Function Keys 12  
Driver  c:\windows\system32\drivers\hidusb.sys (6.1.7601.17514, 29.50 KB (30,208 bytes), 11/20/2010 10:23 PM)
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest I think you'll get in the registry is the key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum`

All system devices will be enumerated in that key. They won't be listed in a manner as user-friendly as they are in Device Manager though.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which and how many details you want to copy, but a couple of ways include:

- You can get the more common details as text with [`devcon`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272)
- You can select the item you want to copy (hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select multiple/all items). Then right-click and select `Copy`:

  [image: Screenshot of copy menu item in Device Manager Details tab]

Comment: (I had a third way in mind before I started typing, but it seems to have evaporated from my mind. If I remember it, I’ll add it.)